# PHP relationship query

Tags: php, codeigniter, relationship

I am using PHP & jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model
I have two tables

```
Table 1: Class
classId  classStd
-----------------------
1         Prep
3         NUR
4         STD-1
5         STD-2

Table2: Section
sectionId  classId  section  sectionName
---------------------------------------------------
5            1       A         rose
6            1       B         red
7            1       C         green
8            3       A         ROME
9            3       B         PARIS
```

Relationship is : One Class can have many sections.
My function

function section_get(){

```
$this->load->model('Model_section');
// this return all section with its classSTD name correctly
$pages = $this->Model_section->with('class')->get_all();
$this->response($pages);
```

}

Return following response

```
[
    {"sectionId":"5","classId":"1","section":"A","sectionName":"rose","class":{"classId":"1","classStd":"Prep"}},
    {"sectionId":"6","classId":"1","section":"B","sectionName":"red","class":{"classId":"1","classStd":"Prep"}},
    {"sectionId":"7","classId":"1","section":"C","sectionName":"green","class":{"classId":"1","classStd":"Prep"}},
    {"sectionId":"8","classId":"3","section":"A","sectionName":"ROME","class":{"classId":"3","classStd":"NUR"}},
    {"sectionId":"9","classId":"3","section":"B","sectionName":"PARIS","class":{"classId":"3","classStd":"NUR"}}
]
```

**How I can get only specific record, for example where “classId = 1”**

Comment: Does this work: `$pages = $this->Model_section->with('class')->get_many_by('classId',1);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `get_many_by` method:

```
$pages = $this->Model_section->with('class')->get_many_by('classId',1);
```

Comment: Thanks it works.  Is there any way to get specific field like select field1, field2 instead of select *

Comment: Try `$this->Model_section->_database->select('field1, field2')`.

Comment: no thats not working. I used <$this->Model_section->dropdown( 'sectionId', 'classId'); but then I am not able to trigger ->with('class')->get_many_by('classId',3); with it

Comment: Hmm...it should work: `$this->Model_section->_database->select('sectionId'); $pages = $this->Model_section->get_all();`

Comment: Ok. I want to get rid of classId":"1" from "class":{"classId":"1","classStd":"Prep"}. which is my section table. 
My response line is {"sectionId":"5","classId":"1","section":"A","sectionName":"rose","class":{"classId":"1","classStd":"Prep"}}

For example
select a.sectionId, a.sectionName , b.classStd from
class_master a,
section_master b
where a.classId = b.sectionId
and b.classId = 1

Comment: Check [this My_Model](http://avenir.ro/revisiting-my_model-copying-jamie-rumbelow-looking-eloquent/) which is based on "jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model" one.

Comment: You want to look at how CodeIgniter's query builder works for selecting: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: You can probably just refer to the columns with the table names like `$this->Model_section->_database->select('class_master.sectionId, class_master.sectionName, section_master.classStd');`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do the following create a dB query with a join that gets all the information you need then group the results by groupID